# Where do I find my facebook ad's placement ID?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-audience-network, facebook-ads

I'm trying to fill the impression gap of my other ad provider **with Facebook ads (Facebook audience network)** to increase the income of my application.

So far so good, **the testing works, I see the facebook test ad on the emulator**, however, when it comes to this code:

```
fbRewardedVideoAd = new RewardedVideoAd(ctx, "YOUR_PLACEMENT_ID");
```

I simply stuck. Documentation says it is okay for testing but [I should replace this with my real placement id](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/setting-up/ad-setup/android/rewarded-video) which I absolutely cannot find no matter where I'm looking for it and the documentation also fails to state where should I look for it.

**So where is this placement id? What is this at all?**

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find your placement ID under Monetisation Manager-Properties-Your application. (if you have already created the placement ids)

If you have not created you can create a property first(Link your application) and under it you can create ad space and then property ids.

The document is here - [Facebook Business](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/191133327919314?id=211412110064838)

Comment: Thank you Bhelasagar!